# Complex .htaccess rule help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to write a .htaccess file.

I need to redirect addresses such as:

/archives/YYYY/MM/post-name

to

/blog/post-name

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your rewrite engine is on:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/archives/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /blog/$3 [L]
```

You can narrow it down by using `{0-9,4}` for the year and `{0-9,2}` for the month.